# How to send a struct over UDP and receive on the other side?

Tags: c, sockets, networking, udp

I have a very specific question on socket programming. My code is similar to the following.

```
struct data_packet{
   unsigned char seqnumber; 
   char data[500]; 
}

struct data_packet packettosend; 
packettosend.seqnumber = '0'
packettosend.data = 'some binary data' (this could be any length from 0 bytes to 500 bytes) 

//sender code 
char buffer[501]; 
memcpy(buffer, &packettosend, sizeof(packetosend)); 
int s = sendto(socketfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0 , .......other params); 

//receiver code
char recvbuffer[501];
int t = recvfrom(recvsocketdf, recvbuffer, 501, 0 ....other params);
  
How do I set up my receiver to receive the data and save it on a `struct data_packet`?
```

---

The seqnumber is a 1-byte char, and data could be 0 byte to 500 bytes.

I am using `sendto` to send the buffer and `recvfrom` to receive the buffer on the other end.

How do I receive my seqnumber and data on the receiving end? I am very new to C and Socket programming. I appreciate any help.

Comment: You just need a buffer to receive it into, like the one you sent it from. Then you can inspect the packet you received as a `data_packet` (assuming it's the right size)

Comment: Yes but data seems to have garbage values  at the end when the data I sent is less than 500 bytes

Comment: Well you only receive as much as you sent, so reading anything beyond that is a bug. `recvfrom` does _tell_ you how many bytes were received, and you're supposed to use that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible problem:

Code likely writes outside its bounds due to `struct` padding.

```
struct data_packet{
   unsigned char seqnumber; 
   // There maybe padding here.
   char data[500]; 
   // There maybe padding here.
}

struct data_packet packettosend; 
char buffer[501];  // May be too small for `packettosend`
memcpy(buffer, &packettosend, sizeof(packetosend));
```

Alternative: Make `buffer[]` certainly big enough

```
// char buffer[501];
char buffer[sizeof packetosend];
```

---

To send just the data and not certainly not any padding:

Pack the data with an implementation specific keyword (if available)

```
// struct data_packet{
packed struct data_packet{
```

Or perform 2 sends

```
int s1 = sendto(socketfd, &buffer.seqnumber, sizeof buffer.seqnumber, ...);
int s2 = sendto(socketfd, buffer.data, sizeof buffer.data, ...);
```

Or copy carefully

```
#define SEQ_DATA (sizeof buffer.seqnumber + sizeof buffer.data)
char buffer[SEQ_DATA]; 
memcpy(buffer, &buffer.seqnumber, sizeof buffer.seqnumber);
memcpy(buffer + sizeof buffer.seqnumber, buffer.data, sizeof buffer.data);
int s = sendto(socketfd, buffer, sizeof buffer, ...);
```

Adjust `recvbuffer[]` size to match.

Comment: Thank you for your time with this. This looks very promising. There are certain conditions that I need to follow. I can only perform 1 send. And the size of datapacket that I receive cant be more than 501 bytes. How do I go about fixing this issue?

Comment: @MaheshKhanal Use the last "copy carefully"

Comment: Thank you. Copying works as intended. I appreciate it a lot.

Answer (score 1):

My first suggestion is to zero out your buffer before filling it in and sending it out, just to avoid garbage values. And you need to define a protocol - you can only send and receive raw bytes over the network. Make it so that the receiving end interprets the first byte as the sequence number, and the rest as the actual message itself. This can be done by simply casting the recvbuffer into a `struct data_packet`, as the underlying byte layout is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I concur with Dennis Afanasev. To elaborate on the casting strategy, read all 501 bytes (including partial/incomplete reads) then cast into the pointer variable e.g.:

```
struct data_packet *dataRecv = (struct data_packet *)&recvbuffer[0];
```

Then you can dereference dataRecv to access the struct, as in dataRecv->seqnumber and dataRecv->data.